# Please comment this method of storing user password... 

Tags: php, security, encryption, passwords, md5

```
$storePassword = md5Hash($salt, $userActuallyPassword);
```

When the user assign a password, I will generate a salt, which is a ten digit random string, and I use md5 with the userActuallyPassword, and I store the salt and storePassword, within store the user actually password, is this a good way to do so? Any comment on this?

Comment: What programming language/framework are you working in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a more rigorously-studied method like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2). You'll still store a hash and a salt, and you can pick your own hashing algorithm, but you'll take care of dictionary attacks, rainbow attacks and a variety of other problems. You can find a good implementation in the comments for the [hash_hmac()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) function.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. PBKDF2 is a Key stretching algorithm, it is not designed for hashing password for storage.

Comment: @Jacco, PBKDF2 is often used for hashing, and it's certainly a more secure choice (strictly speaking) than the MD5 method posted in the question. You're correct that it's a key stretching algorithm, but why does that make it inappropriate for hashing passwords for storage? Surely, passwords are being hashed in this case to protect users in the event the database is compromised.

Comment: The cryptography people tend to disagree with you: [Is PBKDF2-based “better” for Unicode Password hashing than traditional methods?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2051/is-pbkdf2-based-system-cryptology-rfc2898derivebytes-better-for-unicode-passw/2056#2056)

Comment: @Jacco, it looks to me like it's not definitive. PBKDF2 was _published_ as a key derivation function and not for password hashing, but most said that it's suitable (and even recommended) for that purpose. (It's obviously important to pick a strong underlying PRF, but SHA-2 can serve that purpose.)

Comment: from the same post: *"A KDF is not meant for anything else, in particular password storage."*

Answer (score 5):

It's almost good.

However, you should not use MD5, and you should use non-ASCII salt.

[Instead, use bcrypt](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html)

Answer (score 1):

nearly correct:

`$storePassword = $salt . md5Hash($salt, $userActuallyPassword);`

and instead of md5, you are better off using either SHA256 or BCrypt Hash.
Also, a ten digit random string does not have a very large entropy, you could improve by using 128 random bits instead of digits.

Comment: You may want to also mention that the salt can be random for each instance since you append it in plain text to the password (assuming it's a static length like 5 char).  That way even if someone does create rainbow tables for the salt it would only net them 1 password.

Comment: oh, yes, a salt *must* be random. If it is not random, for each instance, it is not a salt.